# how to change the primary key field of a table in Gorm?

Tags: go, go-gorm

my table primary key is `u_id`, but in Gorm's conventions is `id`, even though I have reclaim them in struct.

```
type Users struct {
gorm.Model
UId            uint           `gorm:"column:u_id;primaryKey"`
Password          string    `gorm:"column:u_password"`
}
```

But when I do a .First() query, it said "Unknown column 'siam_users.id' in 'order clause'", and the SQL goes to

```
SELECT * 
FROM `siam_users` 
WHERE u_account = '' AND `siam_users`.`deleted_at` 
IS NULL ORDER BY `siam_users`.`id` LIMIT 1
```

How do I fix that?

Comment: you are making mistake in struct name 'Users' change it into 'SiamUsers'

Comment: If you have a TableName method for Users to return 'siam_users', then this should work.  I've tested this myself, and gorm honors the `primaryKey` tag in the auto Ordering that it does on First, Last, Take.